# Asp.net Identity Role in User Table Users.IsAdmin

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET Idenetity in my project.

My Users table contains a column "IsAdmin" to identify if a user is admin or not.

In the below code

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    }
```

I want to authorize user as admin from table Users.IsAdmin=true. Not from UserRoles table.

Please suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 3 options:

1. Implement IUserRoleStore for ASP.net Identity - it allows you to override IsInRole method
2. When authenticating check if `IsAdmin = true` and add Admin role to this user (so you could use default Authorize attribute).
3. Write a custom Authorization attribute that will contain all the required authorization logic.